# Point domain and subdomain from Route53 to DigitialOcean using https

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, amazon-route53

I have two wordpress sites running on two digitialocean droplets.
They both have ssl certificates and redirects all requests to https.

Let's call the first adresse https://my-freenom-domain-1.ml

Let's call the second adresse https://my-freenom-domain-2.ml

I have a domain registered on route53. Let's call the domain my-domain.com.

I'm trying to map (not redirect) all requests from https://my-domain.com to https://my-freenom-domain-1.ml
and all request from https://subdomain.my-domain.com to https://my-freenom-domain-2.ml

How would you do this?

*Update:*

What I've tried (That didn't work)

1. Creating a simple CNAME.

CNAME for main domain (my-domain.com):

Cannot create a CNAME for main domain and gives the following error:
`RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name my-domain.com. is not permitted at apex in zone my-domain.com.`

CNAME for subdomain (subdomain.my-domain.com):

I am able to create a CNAME for the subdomain, but requests are redirected.
So when I go to subdomain.my-domain.com I'm redirected to https://my-freenom-domain-2.ml

2. Create a S3 "redirect-bucket"

I've tried creating a S3 bucket that redirects all requests for the subdomain.
So bucket named subdomain.my-domain.com, redirects all redirects to https://my-freenom-domain-2.ml (https).
I then created a CNAME for subdomain.my-domain.com pointing to subdomain.my-domain.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.
But all requests are still redirected...

Comment: Add a CNAME record on route53?

Comment: I tried that but it somehow redirects the requests instead. I will update the question with the different solutions i've tried (that didn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on @mdeora's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116769/1051624) correct answer with some details.

**1. Create a virtual host for the domain (my-domain.com) in the droplet**

Copy default conf:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-domain.com.conf
```

Add a ServerName to the conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName my-domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the site: `a2ensite my-domain.com.conf`

Reload apache: `systemctl reload apache2`

**2. Install a ssl certificate on the droplets server**

(I did it using certbot)

`certbot --apache -d my-domain.com`

(follow the certbot instructions)

**3. Create an A record in route53**

Create an A record and point it to the ip of the droplet.

**(4. update wordpress settings)**

If you're running a wordpress site be sure to change wordpress url settings in admin to https://my-domain.com.

Now, hopefully, everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a virtual host for your new domain on your Digital Ocean droplets for it to work.
So I would do following to make it work -

- Create virtual host for the new domain on the webserver of droplets,
  or add the new domain as server in the webserver config.
- Add the SSL certificates of the new domain to the old webserver or alternatively terminate the ssl at the ELB.
- Add the DNS CNAME or A record entry for the new domain pointing to the old domain servers.

Post this it should work.